# Display a text field after a checkbox is checked in jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter

I've got one div with a filter, like this: 
(The classname of the checkboxes is=> **dynamicFilterInput**)

```
[ ] all product
[ ] bmw
[ ] mercedes
[x] audi
```

When one on more checkboxes have been checked, text has to be appeared in another `<div>` like this:

> Filters selected:
>
> • Audi
>   **uncheck all**

I've got no idea how to do that, I have tried this:

```
$(".dynamicFilterInput").on( "click", function() {
    $( "#tabs_pieces_select" ).html( $("input:checked").val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

But it doesn't work.
I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/WPnkh/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Imported jquery ? at the top ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `on` exists as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: We have version 1.4.2, I have to keep I can not unfortunately change :(

Comment: if multiple checkboxes are selected then what do you want to display? do you want to display all the selected items

Comment: i want display just checkbox are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this out http://jsfiddle.net/5KdfB/

Basically your code below will somehow work but some minor issues.

$(".dynamicFilterInput").click(function() {
$( "#tabs_pieces_select" ).html( $("input:checked").val() + " is checked!" );

This would only post the first input checkbox that is checked, and but what if we check two or more checkboxes... your code would only show the first input checkbox.

$('.dynamicFilterInput').on('click', function() {
    var choice = $(this);

```
if (choice.is(":checked"))
{
    $('#choices' ).append( choice.val()  + " is checked!" );
}
```

});

hope this helps

Comment: this is exactly what i need but it doesn't work, on my console error i've "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function", i've 1.4.2 jquery version and i cant change that :( my fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/WPnkh/

Comment: if you are required to use older version of jquery, you can change the .on() to .delegate.. but using newer version of jquery is easier and offer a lot of features :)

Comment: yes I know, I try to pass the new version of jquery in my work, but they are afraid of change ..

Comment: you can also use .bind in earlier version of jquery... check my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5KdfB/1/

Comment: this works with click function ! i cant vote for you my reputation is below 15pts.

How can you when user, uncheck this field remove html.val(is checked....) ?

Comment: you can check the updated fiddle if you want to remove unchecked fields http://jsfiddle.net/5KdfB/2/

Comment: watching the fiddle, it is well prove the value of the input, but would it be possible to bring up something else of value?

Comment: what do you mean by something else of value?

Comment: when you select "TRW" for example, you have ID ("2") display on the div, just how i can change this value for to have "TRW" display when i check "TRW"

Answer (score 2):

For version 1.4.2 use 'delegate'/'bind'. Infact, if you are not dynamically adding the checkboxes, then there is no need to use on/delegate/bind. Simple click would do.

```
$(".dynamicFilterInput").click(function() { 
 $("#tabs_pieces_select").html($(this).val() + " ::: is checked");
});
```

The above code is to be used for simply using the click function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".dynamicFilterInput").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) $("#tabs_pieces_select").html($(this).val() + " is checked!");
});
```

This function is always called whether you check or un-check a checkbox, so we need to make sure that when the check-box is clicked and it is checked, then only the text appears on another div.

Comment: great ! how can you remove when this checbkox is uncheck after add text ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/WPnkh/2/

Comment: it's perfect ! i love you too :p
but watching the fiddle, it is well prove the value of the input, but would it be possible to bring up something else of value?

Comment: Something else, like what? The selected check-box text may be?

Comment: yes, because in my value i have id of product i cant change :(

Comment: when I select a checkbox, as I text "undefined"

Comment: We need to set the `text` for all the check boxes like <input type="checkbox" id="filterID22" value="22" class="dynamicFilterInput" `data-text="Record"`>

Comment: it's ok, i've changed choice.data("text") by choice.attr("data-text") and it works, thx for help !

Answer (score 0):

Use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(".dynamicFilterInput").live("click", function() {
    $("#tabs_pieces_select").html($("input:checked").val()
            + " is checked!");
});
```